# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maskrcnn_benchmark'

Tags: docker, machine-learning, benchmarking

I am doing MLperf, object_detection project test.

https://github.com/mlperf/training/tree/master/object_detection

Question 1:
When doing:

```
nvidia-docker run -v .:/workspace -t -i --rm --ipc=host mlperf/object_detection \
"cd mlperf/training/object_detection && ./install.sh"
```

It responses:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters.
```

I need to change -v .: to -v $(pwd):/workspace

Question 2:

When applied to the modification above, I got a new error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd mlperf/training/object_detection && ./install.sh\": stat cd mlperf/training/object_detection && ./install.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

It seems docker can't accept a string with space, ex: "cd xxxxxxx && ./install.sh"

If I modified the string to single command (./install.sh)

```
nvidia-docker run -v $(pwd):/workspace -t -i --rm --ipc=host mlperf/object_detection \
"./install.sh"
```

This will work, it doesn't look like an incorrect path problem, I tested to use an absoluted path it got the same error.

Question 3:
After followed the steps in the webpage, I always got an error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maskrcnn_benchmark'

```
root@nvme:/markkang/mlperf/training/object_detection# nvidia-docker run -v $(pwd):/workspace -t -i --rm --ipc=host mlperf/object_detection "./run_and_time.sh"

/workspace/pytorch /workspace
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tools/train_mlperf.py", line 8, in <module>
from maskrcnn_benchmark.utils.env import setup_environment  # noqa F401 isort:skip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maskrcnn_benchmark'
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit `train_mlperf.py` and insert the following path code before the invocation of `maskrcnn_benchmark.utils.env`, e.g.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/workspace/pytorch/')

from maskrcnn_benchmark.utils.env import setup_environment  # noqa F401 isort:skip
```